# How to use cross join in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

Using MS - Access 2003

Table

```
S.No   Details

1      name
2      address
3      email
4      phone
5      fax
```

and so on...,

I want to combine all the details for the s.no’s. Like

Expected Output

```
S.No Details

1    name
     address 
     email
     Phone
     Fax
2    address
     name
     email
     phone
     fax
3    email 
     name
     address
     phone
     fax
4    phone
     name
     address
     email
     fax
5    fax
     name
     address 
     email
     Phone
```

and so on..,

Cross join is not accepting in access 2003? Any other solution for this.

Need query help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want to accomplish, but the syntax for a full cartesian product (cross join) is `select * from table1, table2`

If you don't want to cross everything but only some columns, something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (select id from details) b, (select detail from details) c
;
```

should work:

```
id  detail
1   name
2   name
3   name
4   name
5   name
1   email
2   email
....
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to do this in the graphical query builder all you need to do is add both tables and ensure there is no link between them.