# CROSS JOIN of query and single-row table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007, cross-join

I have a big query and a table with a single row  (I store some constants in it).

What is the best way to join the row of the table with every row of the query considering that Access doesn't support cross joins with queries?

```
SELECT * from (subquery), table -- Invalid in Access
```

Comment: your cross join should be fine: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx#BMcross

Comment: maybe this 'fake cross join' is legal in access? SELECT * from (some query) q JOIN  table t ON 1=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access will accept a cross join between a query named `some_query` and a table named `some_table` like this ...

```
SELECT *
FROM some_query, some_table;
```

With your names, try it this way ...

```
SELECT * from [some query], [table]
```

IOW, get rid of the parentheses, and enclose the data source names in square brackets because of the space in `some query` and because `table` is a reserved word.

OTOH, if you meant `some query` to be a placeholder for the text of a SQL statement instead of the name of a saved query, consider this example.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM agents) AS sub, Dual;
```

Comment: Yes, I meant `some query` to be a placeholder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx) and [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231676/how-to-use-cross-join-in-access), cross joins are legal.  You say is it **invalid**, but did you get an error message when you tried?