# MS Access SQL Product Combination Export

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I'm a bit rusty in SQL and could really need some help here - pretty please.

I have an online shop system based on MS Access in my hands and I need to export all possible product variants.

I have a table "VariantTypes" which contains all needed information.
It looks like this:

```
ProductFKID | VariantTypeFKID | VariantValueFKID | Surcharge
```

The data for one product looks like this:

`2 | 3 | 12 | 0,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 13 | 39,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 14 | 39,00 €`

`2 | 134 | 556 | 0,00 €`

`2 | 134 | 557 | 90,00 €`

`2 | 134 | 558 | 90,00 €`

Now for the new import I need every possible variant combination, which should look like this:

`2 | 3 | 12 | 0,00 € | 134 | 556 | 0,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 12 | 0,00 € | 134 | 557 | 90,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 12 | 0,00 € | 134 | 558 | 90,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 13 | 39,00 € | 134 | 556 | 0,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 13 | 39,00 € | 134 | 557 | 90,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 13 | 39,00 € | 134 | 558 | 90,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 14 | 39,00 € | 134 | 556 | 0,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 14 | 39,00 € | 134 | 557 | 90,00 €`

`2 | 3 | 14 | 39,00 € | 134 | 558 | 90,00 €`

And of course, if I have 3 variant types for one product, it should work the same way. The best example for this is:

A product with the colors BLACK, WHITE, RED and sizes S,M,L
and I need:

Black - S | Black - M | Black - L| White - S | White - M | White - L | Red - S |...

I'm sure there is an easy way to solve this, 'cause I learned it quite some time ago in school. I just can't remember how.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Greets,
KaptainEaglu

**UPDATE:**

I managed to create following statement to create the cartesian product:

> SELECT v1.ProductID, v1.Name, v1.Value, v1.Surcharge, v2.Name, v2.Value, v2.Surcharge
>
> FROM [smartstore].[dbo].[smarstorevariants] v1
>
> CROSS JOIN [smartstore].[dbo].[smarstorevariants] v2
>
> WHERE v1.ProductID = v2.ProductID AND v1.Name != v2.Name
>
> ORDER BY v1.ProductID desc

But as a result I don't get 9 combinations as result but 18.
E.g.: Black-S, Black-M,...
and S-Black, S-White,...

I know, technically they are different combinations but for my shop-export they are double combinations.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You are asking for a *Cartesian Product*; implemented with CROSS JOIN operator and no ON clause.

Comment: but ms-access doesn't support cross joins, afaik?

Comment: First Google search on "ms-access sql cross join": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231676/how-to-use-cross-join-in-access

Comment: i just created an odbc-export from ms-access and created an MS-SQL Server Table.

Comment: When SQL Server is available it will always be a better choice for the data storage solution than MS-Access, even though the front end might remain in MS-Access.

Comment: I worked out the CROSS JOIN, but the problem with the cartesian product is, that I get the combinations twice. with following SQL statement, for the above example,I don't get 9 rows but 18... Black-S, Black-M, and so on. and then vice versa S-Black, S-White, S-Red... What can I do? 
SELECT v1.ProductID, v1.Name, v1.Value, v1.Surcharge, v2.Name, v2.Value, v2.Surcharge
FROM [smartstore].[dbo].[smarstorevariants] v1
CROSS JOIN [smartstore].[dbo].[smarstorevariants] v2
WHERE v1.ProductID = v2.ProductID AND v1.ProductID = '2000.w004' AND v1.Name != v2.Name
ORDER BY v1.ProductID desc

Comment: Add the update to your question where can be formatted to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier in Access SQL:

ProductFKID | VariantTypeFKID | VariantValueFKID | Surcharge

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    v1.ProductFKID, 
    v1.VariantTypeFKID, v1.VariantValueFKID, v1.Surcharge,
    v2.VariantTypeFKID, v2.VariantValueFKID, v2.Surcharge    
FROM 
    VariantTypes As v1,
    VariantTypes As v2
WHERE 
    v1.ProductFKID = v2.ProductFKID  
    AND 
    v1.VariantTypeFKID <> v2.VariantTypeFKID 
ORDER BY 
    v1.ProductFKID Desc
```